# Weird LNK2001: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to make a small C project using Visual Studio 2010. Now I have a problem that is very weird.

I want no dependencies so I compile with these linker arguments:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT")
#pragma comment(linker,"/NODEFAULTLIB:MSVCRT")
```

I implemented my own rudimentary memset function like this:

```
void __cdecl _zeromem(char * data,int len)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        *data = 0x00;
        data++;
    }

}
```

I am trying to spawn a process using CreateProcess API the problems occur when I use this:

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

_zeromem((char *)&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
_zeromem((char *)&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO)); //line that causes linker error
```

If I comment the second line zeroing memory in STARTUPINFO it compiles fine, if not I receive:

```
core.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _memset
D:\myapp.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Now what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the optimizer is recognizing what your loop is doing and replacing it with a call to _memset, which is not available when you specifically exclude the standard library.

Comment: how can I prevent such optimization ?

Comment: You can set optimization flags in C/C++ Optimization properties for your configuration in the project settings.  You might have to turn off all optimization to prevent this.